# How to paste a Peek video/animation in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, video, linux, animations

Peek (on Linux) offers four formats to record the screen, and none of them seem to work when copied and pasted:

- GIF/APNG: I get a picture at the time of copying instead of the Peek video.
- WebM/MP4: I cannot copy and paste.

Peek menu:
[image]

Yet, I know that it must work somehow since I have a Google Doc that has a working GIF which I put in there. I just do not know anymore how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy and paste the video/animation, then it becomes just a screenshot of the time when you copied it. GIF and APNG work if you instead go to the menu:

- Google Docs: Insert --> Image --> "Upload from your computer"

Other Google Editors

- Google Sheets: Insert --> "Insert image over cells" (does not work with "Insert image in cell")
- For Google Slides and Google Forms, I did not test it, but it should work as well with the menu.

Side remark: APNG is the smaller size version of GIF, which should be first choice for online sheets, see [APNG vs GIF. Which is Better? [closed] - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774336/apng-vs-gif-which-is-better)